# Does sympy give me wrong results for the second quantization commutators?

Tags: python-3.6, physics, sympy

I am using the following code in `sympy`:

```
from sympy.physics.secondquant import F, Fd, NO, Commutator
from sympy import symbols

a, b, c, d = symbols("a,b,c,d")

comm = NO(Commutator( Fd(a) * F(b), Fd(c) * F(d) ).doit())
print(comm)
# gives me 0
```

Clearly, this should not be zero.

Well, maybe I do not understand `sympy`. Here is what I want to calculate:
[F†_a F_b, F†_c F_d] with not necessarily equal indices a, b, c and d.